# homework about convex set

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $C$ be a nonempty convex subset of $\mathbb R^k$.

Let $x\in\mathbb R^k$. Assume that  $x$ is not an interior point of $C$.

Show that there exists a vector $a$ not equal to $0$ such that

a'x ≤a'y  for all y in C

where a' denotes the transpose of a.

Could you give some hint about this question?

I don't know how to start from where.

Comment: Hint: start by proving this for the special case where $x$ is the zero vector.

Comment: This is asking you to show that some $k-1$-plane through $x$ has all of $C$ on one side of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way: Let $\overline C$ be the closure of $C$. If $x\notin\overline C$, then you can use $a=(z-x)/\|z-x\|$ where $z\in\overline C$ is the point closest to $x$ (you need to prove this, of course, including the existence of $z$). Note that $a$ is a unit vector. If $x\in\overline C$, consider a sequence outside $\overline C$ converging to $x$ and the corresponding vectors $a$. Use a compactness argument.